# How can I solve this React-Router URL params error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to pass URL params to React-Router but Getting an error...

**AppRouter.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Switch, BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Dashboard from '../components/Dashboard'
import Create from '../components/Create'
import Edit from '../components/Edit'
import Header from '../components/Header'
import Help from '../components/Help'
import PageNotFound from '../components/PageNotFound'

const AppRouter = () => {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
                <Header />
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact={true} path="/" component={Dashboard} />
                    <Route path="/create" component={Create} />
                    <Route path="/edit/:id" component={Edit} />
                    <Route path="/help" component={Help} />
                    <Route component={PageNotFound} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}

export default AppRouter
```

**Edit.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router'

const Edit = () => {

    const { id } = useParams()
    console.log(id)

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Edit</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Edit
```

Below I have provided error image...

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izjPE.png)

I have configured webpack myself and if someone wants it then I can provide details for that too but I think this will be enough.

Comment: Your project is looking for a file named bundle.js on the route. React-router only handles your SPA routing, not files required directly in code.